# How to set Instance variable after use callback function in javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop

I suppose the code this :

Item.js

```
var item = {
    id = 0,
    itemname = "name",

    callAjax : function(){
        var ajaxdata = {itemname:this.itemname}
        MM.callajax("apiname",ajaxdata,function(data){
          //this is callback function after ajax is done
          id = data;    // suppose data = 2
        });
    },

}
```

MMCallajax.js

```
var MM = {
   callajax: function (apiname, data, callback) {

    var apiurl = this.apiBaseUrl + "/" + apiname;
    jQuery.ajax( 
               apiurl, 
               {'type': 'POST', 
                'dataType': 'json', 
                'data': data, 
                'xhrFields': { withCredentials: true }
               })
    .done(this.apiCbDone(callback))
   },

   apiCbDone : function (callback) {...},
}
```

I want to update id variable in item object equal data variable after use callback function

How to solve this?

Comment: what are you asking? what's `MM`? what's `callajax`? what the hell does it have to do with OOP?

Comment: First of all, your code has wrong syntax

Comment: Ok, I edit my code again. MM is class about call ajax. I don't want you to  know MM class. Because It's very long code. But I want you to know after call ajax. it will return data = 2;

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors in your code, what you're trying to do is impossible for three reasons: 1. the callback function is executed asynchronously, `id` won't yet be assigned later in your code, 2. `id` is not a variable, you can't assign a value to it (though javascript is kind and will accept this if you do not `use strict`) and 3. even if `id` were a variable, I don't event think it's in the context of a double nested function like that...

Comment: @reverse_engineer I think this is a good answer. your reason make me change my code. But now, I fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @HackerDewdie No problem, if you want more help, tell me what you're trying to do and I can try to help. Basically it's never a good idea to do: `var id;jQuery.ajax(...,...,function(data){id=data;}); goOnUsingId(id);` because the callback function is executed asynchronously (later), which means that the rest of your code (what I called `goOnUsingId(id)`) will still have `id` as `undefined` because it executes before the callback... the good way is to continue the execution flow within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
var item = { id: 0 };
MM.callajax("apiname",ajaxdata,function(data){
    //this is callback function after ajax is done
    item.id = data;    // suppose data = 2
});
```